Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses
Can someone please explain this error and how to get around it? I keep getting:

D:\A New Project\Proforma\UserLogon.vb(31,24): error BC30800: Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses.
D:\A New Project\Proforma\UserLogon.vb(31,29): error BC32017: Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

Whenever I try to insert data into the table described below.
Thanks,
Table Definition:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogonTable] (
    [Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [DateIn]   SMALLDATETIME NULL,
    [DateOut]  SMALLDATETIME NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Dim dteAdded As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
        'Dim dteAdded As DateTime = Now()
        Dim dteAdded As DateTime
        'Dim stmnt As String = "Insert into LogonTable(UserName) values ('" & AuthUser & "')"
        Stop
        If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
            If IsAuthenticated() = True Then
                AuthUser = TextBox1.Text
                'dteAdded = Now()
                Stop
                'SQL.ExecQuery("Insert into LogonTable(UserName, DateIn) values ('" & AuthUser & "', '" & dteAdded & "'")
                'SQL.ExecQuery("Insert into LogonTable(UserName, DateIn) values (AuthUser,dteAdded)")
                Insert into LogonTable(UserName, DateIn) values (AuthUser,Now())
    
                Me.Hide()
                MainScreen.Show()
                'Me.Close()
            End If
        End If
end sub


Please tag the appropriate programming language used

Of course you can't just write SQL code in VB and expect the compiler to know the difference. Your SQL code is being interpreted as VB code and is obviously not valid VB.

Just format the date in SQL Statement
SQL.ExecQuery("Insert into LogonTable(UserName, DateIn) values ('" & AuthUser & "', '" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm") & "'")

Thank you.

This could be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Yes, you are right. But the issue was regarding syntax. Thank you.

Circumvented the problem by declaring DateTime as String:
        AuthUser = TextBox1.Text
        Dim dteAdded As String

        Stop
        dteAdded = Now().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")

        'convert date time to string
        SQL.SQLDS.Clear()
        SQL.ExecQuery("Insert into LogonTable(UserName, DateIn) values ('" & AuthUser & "', '" & dteAdded & "')")

Thx

That's very bad and leaves you open to SQL injection. You should learn how to use parameters with ADO.NET and modify your DAL to support them if it doesn't already.

Will do that when I actually develop a project. At the moment I'm just trying to learn .net. Thanks
